# Mdx - Flag -Actual

Tags: mdx, olap-cube

I have two dimensions  `DimFlag` and `DimPNL` and a fact table `FactAmount`. I am looking to:

```
When pnl is stat(Is Stat=1) : sum (Actual x FlagId)
```

For `pnl`  I multiply the amounts by field `FlagId` basically if it will be so `0 0 X = 0` ...

**DimFlag**

```
FlagId  FlagLabel
-----------------
1       NotClosed
0       IsClosed
```

**DimPNL**

```
PNLId  PNLName  Is Stat
1       a        1
2       test     1
3       test2    0
```

**FactAmount**

```
  id    PNLId     FlagId  Actual
  1      1        1        100
  2      2        1        10
  3      3        0        120
```

I tried the following MDX but it didn't work, any idea please ?

```
Scope (
        [Dim PNL].[PNL].members,[Measures].members     

);   


this = iif([Dim PNL].[PNL].CurrentMember.Properties("Is Stat") =1 
,
aggregate([Dim PNL].[PNL].currentmember,[Measures].currentmember)* iif([Dim Flag].[Flag Label].[Flag Label].currentmember = 0, 0, 1),
aggregate([Dim PNL].[PNL].currentmember,[Measures].currentmember)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this type of calculation can be done in MDX, the MDX can get complex and performs bad. I would suggest to explicitly do the calculation e. g. in the DSV or a view on the fact table that you then use instead of the fact table directly in the DSV. The result of the calculation would then be another column on which you can base a standard measure.

To do it in the DSV, assuming you use a relational table as the base for the fact table, add a named calculation to it, define the column name however you like, and use the expression `Actual * FlagID`. For the other calculation, you may need a subselect, i. e. the expression would be `Actual * case when pnlId in(1,2) then 1 else 0 end`. You can use any SQL that works as a column expression in the select list as the expression in for a named calculation.

Implementing the same in a view on FactAmount, you could implement the second expression better, as then you could join table DimPNL in the view definition and thus use column IsStat in the calculation. Then you would replace table FactAmout by the view, which has the two additional measure columns.

In either case, just define two measures on the two new columns in the cube, and you are done.

As a rule, calculations that are done on record level in the fact table before any aggregation should be done at data loading time, i. e. as described above.

Comment: How can I do it in my case ? I didn't get very well the solution .

Comment: @user3665487 I added a detailed description of the process.